# Add double quotes in .CSV comma delimited file using awk

Tags: csv, awk

Hi I need to elaborate a big csv file (20M rows) adding double quotes for every comma delimited field. The csv file got 8 fields coma delimited as below:

```
'2016-03-12','12393659','134',,'35533605',189348,9798,gmail.com;live_com.com
'2016-03-12','12390103','138',,'35438006',5133,1897,google.com
'2016-03-12','45616164','139',,'01318800',10945593,596633,facebook.com;tumblr.com;t.co
'2016-03-12','45673436','38',,'86441702',4350985,150327,serving-sys.com;chartboost.com;admarvel.com;mydas.mobi;adap.tv;cloudfront.net
```

As you see first 3 fields are between single quotes, 4th is blank, 5th between single quotes and 6th to 8th only comma delimited.
I would like to get the following result (also 4th field even if empty need to be double quoted):

```
"2016-03-12","12393659","134","","35533605","189348","9798","gmail.com;live_com.com"
"2016-03-12","12390103","138","","35438006","5133","1897","google.com"
"2016-03-12","45616164","139","","01318800","10945593","596633","facebook.com;tumblr.com;t.co"
"2016-03-12","45673436","38","","86441702","4350985,"150327","serving-sys.com;chartboost.com;admarvel.com;mydas.mobi;adap.tv;cloudfront.net"
```

I partially obtain result with mix of sed and awk:

```
sed -e s/\'//g inpu.csv > output.csv eliminate quotes
awk '{gsub(/[^,]+/,"\"&\"")}1' output.csv > output1.csv add double quotes
```

but the 4th field is not double quoted and I need to reduce elaboration time as much as possible. 
Anyway help to do all in awk with better performances and also 4th field double quoted.
Many thx for the help. M.Tave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is really that simple with no embedded quotes or newlines or anything then all you need is:

```
$ awk -F"'?,'?" -v OFS='","' '{$1=$1; gsub(/^.|$/,"\"")} 1' file
"2016-03-12","12393659","134","","35533605","189348","9798","gmail.com;live_com.com"
"2016-03-12","12390103","138","","35438006","5133","1897","google.com"
"2016-03-12","45616164","139","","01318800","10945593","596633","facebook.com;tumblr.com;t.co"
"2016-03-12","45673436","38","","86441702","4350985","150327","serving-sys.com;chartboost.com;admarvel.com;mydas.mobi;adap.tv;cloudfront.net"
```

Comment: Thanx again works great..as usual. Will use this, more compressed code.

Answer (score 1):

give this awk one-liner a try:

```
 awk -F, -v OFS="," -v re="^'?|'?$" -v q='"' 
                  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i)gsub(re,q,$i);else $i=q$i q}7' file
```

The idea is, using `gsub()` to add double quotes to those non-empty fields. Those empty fields, just add `"` to the head and tail. The replace regex was defined as awk variable outside the script, for avoiding to escape.

It works with your input data here:

```
kent$  awk -F, -v OFS="," -v re="^'?|'?$" -v q='"' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i)gsub(re,q,$i);else $i=q$i q}7' f
"2016-03-12","12393659","134","","35533605","189348","9798","gmail.com;live_com.com"
"2016-03-12","12390103","138","","35438006","5133","1897","google.com"
"2016-03-12","45616164","139","","01318800","10945593","596633","facebook.com;tumblr.com;t.co"
"2016-03-12","45673436","38","","86441702","4350985","150327","serving-sys.com;chartboost.com;admarvel.com;mydas.mobi;adap.tv;cloudfront.net"
```